# Load Images on by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to make a fancy photo gallery where as the images load there is some animation that allow them to be shown,

The problem is the images are loading so fast that the effect happens at the same time and doesn't look right.

So

I'm trying to queue them in a array and get a repeating script to show them one at a time.

Ive made a atempt but it doens't work.

Here what I have done so far.

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

   $imagesloader = Array();

   $('.tile img').load(function() {
          $(this).css('display', 'none');
          $imagesloader.push(this);
    });

    setInterval(function(){ 

        if($imagesloader.lenght > 0)
        {
          $($imagesloader[0]).show('slide');
          $imagesloader.shift();

        }
    },500)

});



</script>

<style>

.tile {
background-color: #CCC;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
position: absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}

.tile img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.h1 {height:125px;}
.h2 {height:255px;}

.w1 {width:190px;}
.w2 {width:385px;}

.t1 {top:0px;}
.t2 {top:130px;}
.t3 {top:260px;}
.t4 {top:390px;}

.l1 {left:0px;}
.l2 {left:195px;}
.l3 {left:390px;}
.l4 {left:585px;}



.container {
width: 980px;
background: #999;
height: 1000px;
position:relative;

}
</style>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="tile w2 h2 t1 l1">
           <img src="Penguins.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t1 l3">
           <img  src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t1 l4">
           <img  src="Desert.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w2 h2 t2 l3">
             <img  src="Hydrangeas.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t3 l1">
             <img  src="Jellyfish.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t4 l1">
              <img  src="Koala.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h2 t3 l2">
              <img  src="Tulips.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t4 l3">
              <img  src="Tulips.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile w1 h1 t4 l4">
              <img  src="Tulips.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `lenght` in `if($imagesloader.lenght > 0)` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: Many Thanks.  If feel stupid now.

Comment: I'm not sure you can put code in setInterval like that. I believe the code has to go in quotes (someone correct me if I am wrong). Try defining that function with a name and then put the name in quotes where the function is currently defined.

Comment: Ok forget that - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp says you can define it like that (I never realised that was possible). I personally prefer to define functions with names and then put them in `setInterval` (or better still put them in a `setTimeout` and then have the function call itself through another `setTimeout`, so that you know all the code has executed before the next call). It just reads a lot better.

Comment: When doing js programming, first thing you should do - when something doesn't work - is to check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: I thought i did.  Anyway it works and it looks great :)